# Does Pharo have immutable data structures such as maps and sets in its standard library?

Tags: pharo

I might have just missed them, but I can't seem to find any mention of immutable data structures in Pharo. Coming from functional languages, I've found the immutable map and set useful on various occasions. Even though Pharo has a particular bias towards using mutation, I'd be surprised if nobody got around to implementing them yet.

Comment: Your question would be more interesting if you provided an example where immutable objects are required.

Comment: This is true, but it also occurring to me that for most of the examples that I've had in mind it would not have been a bad idea to just copy arrays. Even for things such as calculating the free variables of a functional program it might be possible to work around it by selectively copying mutable `HashSet`s even though immutable data structures would be more elegant.

Comment: Somewhat ironically, the one data structure which is the immutable list would be the one that I could not do without. In [Spiral](https://github.com/mrakgr/The-Spiral-Language) I am using it to accumulate a trace over the compilation and using it when reporting type errors.

Comment: More generally, one pattern I've often used in my programming in F# and Spiral is to selectively update a member of a immutable record when calling a function. This is simply the right thing to do rather than passing a large number of parameters explicitly. I suppose in Pharo such a pattern could be emulated by copying the object and then mutating it instead. Would that be right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code at http://source.lukas-renggli.ch/container/ implements a modern container and iterator library; with mutable and immutable lists; unmodifiable views; and sorted, ordered and unordered set and map data structures. It also supports efficient lazy iteration over all containers using common filtering, mapping, flattening, partitioning, ... operations.

I am not claiming the library has a perfect design or is more performant than the standard collection library, but it is certainly a good starting point for further exploration.

Comment: Interesting. Any reason why this is not on the catalogue? Also I need to apologize to Uko for taking away the accepted answer (for the second time.) Sorry about that, I'll be a bit more patient next time.

Comment: Not sure it works with a current versions of Pharo? This was written in 2012 on Pharo 1.3 and I haven't touched it since then. Feel free to try, modify and republish it in some more modern code repository than http://source.lukas-renggli.ch.

Comment: As it turns out, I had a need for immutable lists a lot earlier than I thought I would. Looking at the code, I am curious as to why your library provides iterators when the Pharo standard library does not use them. Did the design of the standard libraries change in the last 6 years?

Comment: As far as I remember the goal was to fix the horribly inefficient `#collect:`, `#select:`, `#reject:` and `#inject:into:` methods in Smalltalk-80. Each time you call one of these methods your collection is copied. The `Stream` hierarchy attemps to fix that, but it provides a different and incompatible API. The container library tried to unify these two concepts.

Comment: Well, apart from `#inject:into:` isn't the result of those methods supposed to be a brand new collection? How would iterators help with regards to that anyway?

Comment: Chaining `#collect:`, `#select:`, and `#reject:` and possibly ending with `#inject:into:` or any other accessor creates unnecessary intermediate collections. That's the reason why people started to add countless permutations of these methods like `#select:thenCollect:`. Iterators solve that composability problem. Also it was not the goal to create a library that is backward compatible.

Answer (score 3):

It is completely possible that someone implemented something like that. And maybe there will be immutable collections as a part of the main library in the future. However, for now, there is nothing like that and it is for a very simple reason: *what for?* When I started to learn Pharo I was fascinated by the null-propagation idea of Objective-C (if you have null, and you send a message to a null you get null back, etc...) So the first thing that I did was to implement null propagation in Pharo. It was fun, it was educational, and it was completely useless. It was useless because no one uses Pharo in that way, it was a wrong approach for that context. I strongly encourage you to make your own immutable collections in Pharo.

But while you do this, think about what should be immutable and why. Is it about shrinking or growing a collection? Arrays are like that — they are fixed size. Is it about not being able to add/remove/swap elements? But what if you get an element and modify it? Finally, consider this example:

```
array := #('a' 'b' 'c').

array first become: 'd'.

array = #('d' 'b' 'c')
```

I don't use any setters and still, I can end up with a different array in the end.

Pharo community cares about transparency and good design. It is known that you shouldn't modify contents of collections directly, you shouldn't interact with the internal state of the objects from outside, etc… On the other hand, no one will punch you in the face if you want to do that. I mean, what if you prototype? what if you hack? what if there is literally no other way? You are always able to choose, the question is how can we help people to learn about better choices.

P.S. My answer may sound like immutability is not important. It's not the case. There were even prototypes of [read-only objects](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/279263664_Towards_First_Class_References_as_a_Security_Infrastructure_in_Dynamically-Typed_Languages) that can be used to ensure a certain degree of security. It's not that simple to come up with a single concept that will work for *everything* though

Comment: I feel that somebody other than me would be better suited to say what their use would be in standard contexts, but when while working on a language I've found them quite useful. Balanced trees tend to have non-trivial implementations - if they aren't provided as a part of a library they are not something that could be cooked up in 5m. But I suppose porting them from some functional language would not be too hard either.

Comment: By the way, swapping pointers like that is my first time seeing something like that. Feels like quite a dangerous feature, I am not surprised that I cannot find any kind of usage of it apart from a few tests.

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic think of a running system, and then at some point, a class gets re-compiled. How would you implement that? In Pharo first a new version of a class is constructed, and then all the pointers are swapped to the new version, so if an instance has to look up a method it will use a new class. (it's not as trivial, but `become` is very useful in that case)

Comment: Oh, I see. That is quite smart. I am wondering how this plays with JITing though. Not that I know much of anything about JITing of dynamic languages at this point, but I've done something similar and I understand that to specialize code there has to be a snapshot of types of all the variables in the lexical scope. In my own statically typed language I've implemented that sort of thing using memoization. Swapping pointers in dictionary keys would definitely mess with that.